# Linux find, get output to a variable before and after -exec respectively

Tags: shell, find

In a shell script (sh) I want to find an executable file, retain its run output in a variable and its path in another variable.

Say I want to find all installed OpenCV versions, then retain the major in a variable and the location of the file in another variable.

```
list=$(find / -type f -name opencv_version -exec {} \; 2>/dev/null | sort -u | cut -c-1); printf "%c;" $list
```

will return say 3;4; but I also want the `opencv_version` file location for version 3 and 4 respectively.
For that I would need to store the output of the first part `find / -type f -name opencv_version` in another variable, before running `-exec {} \;`

Can I do these two ops in a one liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I don't need `-exec` afterall. This works for me:

`for i in $(find / -type f -name opencv_version 2>/dev/null); do printf '%c in %s\n' $($i) $i; done`

This will return something like:

`4 in /usr/bin/opencv_version`

`3 in /home/user/opencv/build/bin/opencv_version`

Comment: And with echo:
`for i in $(find / -type f -name opencv_version 2>/dev/null); do echo "$($i | cut -c-1)" in $i; done`

Answer (score 0):

Use `-print` **and** `-exec`, and put the output processing in a shell

For example, on my mac with GNU awk installed via homebrew:

```sh
find -L /usr -name awk -type f -executable \
             -print \
             -exec sh -c '"$1" --version | head -n 1' sh {} \;  2>/dev/null
```

outputs

```
/usr/bin/awk
awk version 20200816
/usr/local/bin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/gawk/bin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/gawk/libexec/gnubin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
/usr/local/opt/gawk/bin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
/usr/local/opt/gawk/libexec/gnubin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
/usr/local/Cellar/gawk/5.1.1/bin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
/usr/local/Cellar/gawk/5.1.1/libexec/gnubin/awk
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
```

Those lines can be process in pairs.

Comment: Smart and elegant answer for single processing each file. The question was about `sort` or any other grouping command.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to read list of sorted files into an array.

Than print each array elements followed by with its execution result:

```
readarray -t fileNamesArr < <(find / -type f -name opencv_version -executable 2>/dev/null | sort -u)
for aFileName in ${fileNamesArr[@]}; do printf "%s; %c\n" $aFileName $(aFileName); done
```

Additional suggestion, use `locate` command if possible. It is faster and simpler. If you have frequently udated files lists with `updatedb`.

#### Testing this solution

Reading **sorted** list of all service files in machine.
Than for each serviceFile print its path, and its chars count.

```
readarray -t servicesArr < <(locate "*.service"|sort -u)
for serviceFile in ${servicesArr[@]}; do 
  printf "%s; %s\n" "$serviceFile" $(cat "$serviceFile"| wc -m );
done
```

#### Same solution with `awk`.

Reading sorted list of filenames into awk script that:

Prepares a `printf` command from current fileName. And run it.

```
   awk '{
     bash_script = "printf \"%s; %c\\n\" "$0" $("$0")";
     system("bash -c '\''" bash_script "'\''");
   }' <<< $(find / -type f -name opencv_version -executable 2>/dev/null | sort -u)
```